# jquery image flipping not Working on Internet Explorer 11.Error showing

Tags: jquery

I am getting error as :

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'contains': object is null or undefined.
```

code is :

```
    function cardsTimeout(id, time, card) {
    if (id in timeouts) {
        clearTimeout(timeouts[id]);
    }
    timeouts[id] = setTimeout(function () {
        var c = card.classList;
        var newTime = randomNum(timeMin, timeMax) * 2000;
        c.contains("flipped") === true ? c.remove("flipped") :c.add("flipped");
        cardsTimeout(id, newTime, card);
    }, time);
}
```

Comment: what `card`? how is `cardsTimeout` called

Comment: var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card1.effect__random");
    var timeMin = 1;
    var timeMax = 3;
    var timeouts = [];

    // loop through cards
    for (var i = 0, len = cards.length; i < len; i++) {
        var card = cards[i];
        var cardID = card.getAttribute("data-id");
        var id = "timeoutID" + cardID;
        var time = randomNum(timeMin, timeMax) * 2000;
        cardsTimeout(id, time, card);
    }

Comment: cards are the blocks which flip randomly using Timeout.